# Div element not aligning to top of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a mock up site (OMG! Chrome).

If you change the position of the live preview panel and make it go on the left of your screen, you will see a random gap appear under the navigation bar. I've tried many ways I found here but to no avail.

Here is my code: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbNzLz)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="Google Chrome, Google Chromebooks and Google Chromecast news, apps and more" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="chrome, chromebooks, chromecast, news, apps, more, updates, information, about" />
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="Eduardo Pelaez" />
        <title>OMG! Chrome!</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="382" height="60" alt="OMG! Chrome! logo" id="logo" />
                <div id="navbar-container">
                    <ul id="navbar-ul">
                        <a href="index.html"><li id="dchev">Categories</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="android-nav">Android</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="dchev">Submit a Tip</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li id="dchev">Add</li></a>
                    </ul>
                    <form action="http://www.example.com/subscribe.php" method="get">
                        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search OMG! Chrome!" />
                        <input type="image" src="images/search.png" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="main-section">
                    <img src="images/main-section.jpg" alt="a banner about five powerful Google Keep features" class="main-section-img" /><!-- .main-section-img is 1053x186px -->
                </div>
                <div id="col1">
                    <div id="main-row" class="row">
                        <div class="column-head">
                            <a href="#"><h2 class="entry-title">Google Now Coming to Chrome OS App Launcher</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                            <p>Google recently announced that Google Now will start appearing in the redesigned Chrome App Launcher. This is one of several changes heading to the Beta version of Chrome OS.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="main-row-img">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" alt="Screenshot of Google Now in Chrome App Launcher" title="A screenshot of Google Now in the Chrome App Launcher in Chrome OS beta channel" class="article-img" /></a><!-- .article-img is 350x200px -->
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end #main-row" -->
                    <div id="row2" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row3" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row4" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row5" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row6" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row7" class="row">
                        <div id="l-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/main-row-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="r-article">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/article-img.jpg" class="article-img" /></a>
                            <a href="#">News</a>
                            <a href="#"><h2>Install Google's New &quot;Data Saver&quot; Extension for Chrome</h2></a>
                            <p>By <span class="author">Joey-Elijah Sneddon</span><p>
                            <p>Thursday</p>
                            <p>39 Comments</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="page-nav">
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#"><li>1</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>2</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>3</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>4</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>5</li></a>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="page-nav-next">
                            <a href="#">Next</a><!-- make images/right-chevron.png background img positioned right -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end #col1 -->
                <div id="col2">
                    <img src="images/social-img.jpg" width="300" height="100" alt="" id="social-stats" />
                    <div id="most-read-this-week">
                        <h2><span class="side-bar-title">Most Read This Week</span></h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><img src="images/most-read-img.jpg" class="mini-thumbnail" /><a href="#">This is Chrome&rsquo;s Newest Easter Egg. And It&rsquo;s Awesome</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="latest-videos">
                        <h2><span class="side-bar-title">Latest Videos</span></h2>
                        <div id="latest-videos-thumbnails">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel-two-open.jpg" alt="Left open view of Google's lateset Chromebook Pixel 2" class="latest-video-img" /><!-- .latest-video-img is 145x100 -->
                            Pixel 2</a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/pixel-two-closed.jpg" alt="Right front closed view of Google's latest Chromebook Pixel 2" class="latest-video-img" />
                            Pixel 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="get-our-apps">
                        <h2><span class="side-bar-title">Get Our Apps</span></h2>
                        <div id="get-our-apps-imgs">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/google-play-app.jpg" alt="Get this app on Google Play banner" class="banner" /></a><!-- .banner is 257x95 -->
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/chrome-web-store-extension.jpg" alt="Get this extension on the Chrome Web Store banner" class="banner" /></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/wp-engine-credit.png" alt="Hosted by WP Engine" width="216" height="55" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end #col2 -->
            </div><!-- end #content -->
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="left-footer">
                    <div id="footer-row1" class="footer-row">
                        <h3>Information</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#"><li>Authors</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Code of Conduct</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Privacy Policy</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-row2" class="footer-row">
                        <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#"><li>Contact Form</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Tweet Us</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Mail Us</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-row3" class="footer-row">
                        <h3>Quick Links</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#"><li>Chrome OS News</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Extensions</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Web Apps</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Chromebooks</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer-row4" class="footer-row">
                        <h3>Other Links</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#"><li>Ohso Website</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>OMG! Ubuntu!</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end #left-footer -->
                <div id="right-footer">
                    <div id="share">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share icon" class="share-icon" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share icon" class="share-icon" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share icon" class="share-icon" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share icon" class="share-icon" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/share.png" alt="Share icon" class="share-icon" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <p>&copy; 2015 <a href="#">Ohso Ltd.</a> All rights reserved.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">OMG! Chrome!</a> is a member of the Ohso Ltd Network.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">Chrome</a> is a registered trademark of <a href="#">Google Inc.</a></p>
                    <img src="images/ohso.png" width="125" height="50" alt="Ohso company logo" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- end #footer -->
        </div><!-- end #wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Lato, Ubuntu, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;}
#content, #footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;}
#logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 112px;
    top: 5px;}
#header {
    background-color: #21A4FE;
    height: 75px;}
#navbar-ul {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
    bottom: 2px;}
input[type="search"] {
    height: 36px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;}
form {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 78px;
    top: 3px;}
#navbar-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 28px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 24px;}
#android-nav {
    margin-right: 7px !important;}
#dchev {
    background: url("../images/down-chevron.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 92% 56%;}
#navbar-container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 47px;
    margin-right: 50px;}
/* end navigation bar */
.main-section-img {
    width: 1053px;
    height: 186px;}
#main-section {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 186px;}
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem better? I resized the window and didn't see any problems

Comment: @Chun look at how "banner about " thingy goes down (Also it looks like this happens only in chrome

Comment: It's all over the place on every browser I checked with.

Comment: @Shikkediel it seem to be working fine on Firefox for me

Comment: On on my setup it's above the header or sticking out just from the top when I make the window smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution is in #navbar-container
its height make this jump

try to reduce the height to 10px and you will see the banner set to its right place

Comment: Awesome!
How is the UL element affecting it though?
It's far from the banner.

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar-container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 47px;
    margin-right: 50px;}
```

personally I have using `top`,`bottom`, `left` and `right`. They always screw up thing when you resize window. Please just use margin to position your element. 
if you use:

```
  #navbar-container {
        width: 800px;
        height: 34px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;}
```

then you would have the same style/position but no mysterious space below nav.

Comment: Great solution, but is adding the position property still necessary?